# Convert MAC address std::string into uint64_t

Tags: c++, unix

I have a hexadecimal MAC address held in a std::string.  What would be the best way to turn that MAC address into an integer-type held in a uint64_t?

I'm aware of stringstream, sprintf, atoi, etc.  I've actually written little conversion functions with the first 2 of those, but they seem more sloppy than I would like.

So, can someone show me a good, clean way to convert

```
std::string mac = "00:00:12:24:36:4f";
```

into a uint64_t?

PS: I don't have boost/TR1 facilities available and can't install them where the code will actually be used (which is also why I haven't copy pasted one of my attempts, sorry about that!).  So please keep solutions to straight-up C/C++ calls.  If you have an interesting solution with a UNIX system call I'd be interested too!

Comment: +1. Surprised this hasn't come up before. What's the use case? Is it rare?

Comment: I don't understand the link between not being able to use Boost/TR1 and not showing us your attempts.

Comment: Just dealing with a large network of devices and the MAC makes a good unique identifier given the scenario since its already in place.  It's all XML powered, so I'm getting the values as human-readable text but one of the interfaces requires the MAC as a uint64_t (which is understandable).  I was surprised it wasn't there too :p

Comment: Suffice to say the attempts are on a computer system that I can't access from internet-enabled PCs :(

Comment: You have a keyboard and eyes, do you not? You can't write out code (that you wrote yourself in the first place!) without resorting to copy/paste?

Comment: Haha, yeah - fair enough. I figured it was a quick function someone probably could one or two line in a way I hadn't thought of.  My ways were a little chunky and I knew someone else would come up with something... more elegant? :p

Comment: On SO we generally prefer fixing existing code to providing new code. rentacoder.com is just around the corner ;-)

Comment: You could probably write a neat little loop with `strtoul()`...

Comment: I've been trying to come up with an elegant solution that deletes all the `':'` characters, prepends `"0x"` (yielding `"0x00001224364f"`), and then converts the result to uint64_t.  Perhaps someone who's more familiar with the C++ standard library than I am can try it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
uint64_t string_to_mac(std::string const& s) {
    unsigned char a[6];
    int last = -1;
    int rc = sscanf(s.c_str(), "%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx%n",
                    a + 0, a + 1, a + 2, a + 3, a + 4, a + 5,
                    &last);
    if(rc != 6 || s.size() != last)
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid mac address format " + s);
    return
        uint64_t(a[0]) << 40 |
        uint64_t(a[1]) << 32 | ( 
            // 32-bit instructions take fewer bytes on x86, so use them as much as possible.
            uint32_t(a[2]) << 24 | 
            uint32_t(a[3]) << 16 |
            uint32_t(a[4]) << 8 |
            uint32_t(a[5])
        );
}
```

Comment: I can almost guarantee that someone will shout at you for providing a C-style solution for a C++ question...

Comment: This requires a specific format of MAC address, which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Hey, if its fast then I'm happy regardless of the type of solution. I'm just gonna sit around and see what other people like best before I select any answers.

Comment: I don't think `uint64_t(x)` is a valid C-syntax. And those people can replace `sscanf` with `std::sscanf`. )

Comment: @Maxim: `std::string` isn't valid C syntax either, nor is `throw std::runtime_error(...)`.  The solution isn't meant to be valid C, it just happens to use a function from the standard C library (which is included in the standard C++ library).

Comment: @Maxim: "C-style" doesn't mean "only valid C code". C++ has its own conventions and idioms, and it is these that we prefer to see in C++ code over the C-style alternatives! (Though, @Oli, in this case, `std::sscanf` probably _is_ the best approach. It's only marginally C-style IMO, and not in any pointless way either.)

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm inclined to agree that `sscanf` is possibly neater than the C++ alternative here!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nowadays I would suggest using `std::` versions, since C++ versions are amended to respect the type system, see http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/29/why-cstdlib-is-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/

Answer (score 10):

My solution (requires c++11):

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>


uint64_t convert_mac(std::string mac) {
  // Remove colons
  mac.erase(std::remove(mac.begin(), mac.end(), ':'), mac.end());

  // Convert to uint64_t
  return strtoul(mac.c_str(), NULL, 16);
}
```

Comment: ▒ < -  This is what I got when I tried it.  What does it even mean?

Comment: This is a nice clean answer (although I'd switch to `std::stoull` and get rid of the `c_str`), however there's a big gotcha in that it in the `uint64_t` that gets returned has the bytes reversed if you're on a little endian system (i.e. most systems). If you print the uint64_t in hex it'll look right, but if you print it out byte-by-byte you'll see it's backwards.

Answer (score 3):

Use sscanf:

```
std::string mac = "00:00:12:24:36:4f";
unsigned u[6];
int c=sscanf(mac.c_str(),"%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x",u,u+1,u+2,u+3,u+4,u+5);
if (c!=6) raise_error("input format error");
uint64_t r=0;
for (int i=0;i<6;i++) r=(r<<8)+u[i];
// or:  for (int i=0;i<6;i++) r=(r<<8)+u[5-i];
```

Comment: What happens if you feed it with "abc:def:123:456:789"?

Comment: u[i] is set to values >255. OP could check this if necessary and give a diagnostic. Unfortunately, %hhx doesn't catch this either, does it?

Comment: `sscanf()` just silently ignores overflow (

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any magic tricks.  Here's a random attempt that may or may not be better than what you've done.  It's simplish, but I bet there's far faster solutions.

```
uint64_t mac2int(std::string s) {
    uint64_t r=0;
    std::string::iterator i;
    std::string::iterator end = s.end();

    for(i = s.begin; i != end; ++i) {
        char let = *i;
        if (let >= '0' && let <= '9') { 
            r = r*0xf + (let-'0');
        } else if (let >= 'a' && let <= 'f') { 
            r = r*0xf + (let-'a'+10);
        } else if (let >= 'A' && let <= 'F') { 
            r = r*0xf + (let-'A'+10);
        }
    } 
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Unlike the other answers, mine also accepts "01-23-45-67-89-ab", "0123.4567.89ab" (both valid) and "HAPPY BIRTHDAY TO YOU".

Comment: Strictly speaking, the characters 'a'..'f' and 'A'..'F' aren't guaranteed to have contiguous representations (the digits '0'..'9' are).  In practice, it's not going to be a problem; even EBCDIC, which doesn't make the alphabet contiguous, does make 'a'..'f' and 'A'..'F' contiguous.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

```
uint64_t ParseMac(const std::string& str)
{
  std::istringstream iss(str);
  uint64_t nibble;
  uint64_t result(0);
  iss >> std::hex;
  while(iss >> nibble) {
    result = (result << 8) + nibble;
    iss.get();
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, +1 :)

Comment: huh, clever use of iss.get().

Comment: Not really, as it performs no check that the eaten up character is ':'...

Answer (score 1):

This will just shift hex digits through until the string runs out, not caring about delimiters or total length.  But it converts the input string to the desired uint64_t format.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t cvt(std::string &v)
{
    std::string::iterator i;
    std::string digits = "0123456789abcdefABCDEF";
    uint64_t result = 0;
    size_t pos = 0;

    i = v.begin();

    while (i != v.end())
    {
        // search for character in hex digits set
        pos = digits.find(*i);

        // if found in valid hex digits
        if (pos != std::string::npos)
        {
            // handle upper/lower case hex digit
            if (pos > 0xf)
            {
                pos -= 6;
            }

            // shift a nibble in
            result <<= 4;
            result |= pos;
        }

        ++i;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I was about to criticize the speed of digits.find() but then remembered you have a fixed length of 16, which fits in the cache... That's plenty fast.

Comment: If ultimate speed was the objective, a lookup table should replace the digits string.  I would use a table of 256 uint8_t elements with the valid indices having a value below 16 and all others perhaps 0xff.

Comment: Incidentally, I just remembered there is a standard function that performs the OP's exact operation directly.  It is ether_aton().

Answer (score 1):

Another faster version without calling library functions:

```
inline unsigned read_hex_byte(char const** beg, char const* end) {
    if(end - *beg < 2)
        throw std::invalid_argument("");
    unsigned hi = (*beg)[0], lo = (*beg)[1];
    *beg += 2;
    hi -= hi >= '0' && hi <= '9' ? '0' :
        hi >= 'a' && hi <= 'f' ? 'a' - 10 :
        hi >= 'A' && hi <= 'F' ? 'A' - 10 :
        throw std::invalid_argument("");
    lo -= lo >= '0' && lo <= '9' ? '0' :
        lo >= 'a' && lo <= 'f' ? 'a' - 10 :
        lo >= 'A' && lo <= 'F' ? 'A' - 10 :
        throw std::invalid_argument("");
    return hi << 4 | lo;
}

uint64_t string_to_mac2(std::string const& s) {
    char const *beg = s.data(), *end = beg + s.size();
    uint64_t r;
    try {
        r = read_hex_byte(&beg, end);
        beg += beg != end && ':' == *beg;
        r = r << 8 | read_hex_byte(&beg, end);
        beg += beg != end && ':' == *beg;
        r = r << 8 | read_hex_byte(&beg, end);
        beg += beg != end && ':' == *beg;
        r = r << 8 | read_hex_byte(&beg, end);
        beg += beg != end && ':' == *beg;
        r = r << 8 | read_hex_byte(&beg, end);
        beg += beg != end && ':' == *beg;
        r = r << 8 | read_hex_byte(&beg, end);
    } catch(std::invalid_argument&) {
        beg = end - 1;
    }
    if(beg != end)
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid mac address format " + s);
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More C++11 way without input data validation:

```
uint64_t stomac( const std::string &mac )
{
    static const std::regex r{ "([\\da-fA-F]{2})(:|$)" };

    auto it = std::sregex_iterator( mac.begin(), mac.end(), r );
    static const auto end = std::sregex_iterator();

    return std::accumulate( it, end, 0, []( uint64_t i, const std::sregex_iterator::value_type &v ) {
            return ( i << 8 ) + std::stol( v.str(1), nullptr, 16 );
    } );
}
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/g0uyPW)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ASCII to `struct ether_addr` conversion routine `ether_aton`, or its thread-safe version `ether_aton_r` (GNU extension).

```
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <string>

#define ETHER_ADDR_ERR UINT64_C(~0)

uint64_t ether_atou64( const std::string& addr_str ) {
    union {
        uint64_t          result;
        struct ether_addr address;
    };
    result = 0;
    struct ether_addr* ptr = ether_aton_r( addr_str.c_str(), &address );
    if( !ptr ) {
        return ETHER_ADDR_ERR;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I connot comment yet.

For the answer from @AB71E5, you need to change "strtoul" to "strtoull".
Ex : 01:02:03:04:05:06 = 48bits but "unsigned long" = 32bits.

The final result is :

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>


uint64_t convert_mac(std::string mac) {
  // Remove colons
  mac.erase(std::remove(mac.begin(), mac.end(), ':'), mac.end());

  // Convert to uint64_t
  return strtoull(mac.c_str(), NULL, 16);
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31626271)